# How to bulk SELECT rows with multiple pairs in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.5

Let's say I have a table, `email_phone_notes` that looks like this:

```
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| email                 | varchar      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| phone                 | varchar      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| notes                 | text         | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

So, each email/phone combination is unique, but you could have several email addresses with different phone numbers and vice versa. This is a little contrived but it mirrors my scenario.

I'd like to do a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM email_phone_notes  WHERE email = 'foo@bar.com' AND phone = '555-1212';
```

But, I'd like to do multiple pairs at once so I don't have to make several `SELECT` queries. It's also important to keep the pairs together because I don't want to return an errant phone/email combination that wasn't requested.

I could do something like this, but for the possibility of several hundred values the query will be really long.

```
SELECT * FROM email_phone_notes WHERE ( 
  (email='foo@bar.com' && phone='555-1212') || 
  (email='test@test.com' && phone='888-1212') || 
   ...
```

Is there a more elegant solution, or should I stick with this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you're after elegant SQL, you could use row constructors:

```
SELECT * FROM email_phone_notes WHERE (email, phone) IN (
  ('foo@bar.com'  , '555-1212'),
  ('test@test.com', '888-1212')
  -- etc.
);
```

However, that's not at all index-friendly and would not be recommended on a table of any significant size.  Instead, you could materialise a table with your desired pairs and join that with your table:

```
SELECT * FROM email_phone_notes NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT 'foo@bar.com' AS email, '555-1212' AS phone
UNION ALL
  SELECT 'test@test.com', '888-1212'
-- etc.
) t;
```

Or else pre-populate a (temporary) table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo (PRIMARY KEY (email, phone)) Engine=MEMORY
  SELECT email, phone FROM email_phone_notes WHERE FALSE
;

INSERT INTO foo
  (email, phone)
VALUES
  ('foo@bar.com'  , '555-1212'),
  ('test@test.com', '888-1212')
  -- etc.
;

SELECT * FROM email_phone_notes NATURAL JOIN foo;
```

Comment: Could you explain why the first option is not "index-friendly"? Sources?

Comment: I tested the first option and in MySQL Workbench I don't see "full-scan", so where in doesn't make a full scan if u have an index on (email, phone). In "Statement Analysis" I see normal values in rows sent / rows scanned, etc. Maybe it's not index-friendly, because it firstly search first record, then second, etc.? So, we've O(n) where n is number of elements in "IN".

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [row constructor](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/row-subqueries.html) like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM email_phone_notes
WHERE (email, phone) IN (
  ('foo@bar.com', '555-1212'),
  ('test@test.com', '888-1212')
)
```

[SQLfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55dd5/1/0)

Comment: Sadly won't use the index, though.

Comment: Curse you, MySQL. Well, the original one seems neither: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86c1e/2

Comment: Bear in mind that an index would not be used on that table anyway, as it's too small (fewer than 10 records).

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know you could construct a `WHERE IN` that way. Any idea why an index isn't used?  If I do WHERE email IN (%values%) an index is used there.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier answers are provided almost 10 years ago. It's 2020 now and the answer seems to have changed.

**Short answer**: Use [row constructor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/row-constructor-optimization.html) syntax - the optimizer may (or may not) use an index.

In [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9a636/4) here, the optimizer is able to use the index, even when the row constructor doesn't cover the prefix of the index.