# Filter Data in Sql

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which i want to get data on basis of attribute_id and attribute value pair.I want to pass array of both attribute_ids and its corresponding attribute_values and on basis of that i want to have a sku.There can be different values for same attribute id for same service_id but sku is different.Please suggest me some query.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using IN construct and listing you pairs?

Answer (score 0):

You can select based on pairs:

```
SELECT `sku` FROM `mytable` WHERE (`attribute_id`, `attribute_value`) IN (
    (3, 6000),
    (8, 5000),
    (9, 6)
);
```

Here's a question that offers more insight on that, as well as some more index-friendly alternatives: [MySQL: How to bulk SELECT rows with multiple pairs in WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426203/mysql-how-to-bulk-select-rows-with-multiple-pairs-in-where-clause)